# post edit button on front end

Tags: templates, theme-twenty-eleven

If you are logged-in and switch to the front-end the default Wordpress theme `Twenty Eleven` provides `edit` buttons next to every post.

Pressing this button you get to the certain post's back-end post edit page.

How to implement this into a custom template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is `edit_post_link()` (see [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link) or [source](http://queryposts.com/function/edit_post_link/)). In TwentyEleven it used as follows in `content.php`

```
edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' );
```

You can simply use the function as indicated above (or in the Codex) in a custom template, but it must be used **inside the loop**. There's no need to perform any permission checks.